# PHP script gets progressively slower (file reader)

Tags: php, fopen, fgets, slowdown

I have a script that, when put against a timer, gets progressively slower.  It's fairly simple as all it does is reads a line, checks it then adds it to the database, then proceeds to the next line.

Here's the output of it gradually getting worse:

```
Record: #1,001 Memory: 1,355,360kb taking 1.84s
Record: #1,001 Memory: 1,355,360kb taking 1.84s
Record: #2,002 Memory: 1,355,192kb taking 2.12s
Record: #3,003 Memory: 1,355,192kb taking 2.39s
Record: #4,004 Memory: 1,355,192kb taking 2.65s
Record: #5,005 Memory: 1,355,200kb taking 2.94s
Record: #6,006 Memory: 1,355,376kb taking 3.28s
Record: #7,007 Memory: 1,355,176kb taking 3.56s
Record: #8,008 Memory: 1,355,408kb taking 3.81s
Record: #9,009 Memory: 1,355,464kb taking 4.07s
Record: #10,010 Memory: 1,355,392kb taking 4.32s
Record: #11,011 Memory: 1,355,352kb taking 4.63s
Record: #12,012 Memory: 1,355,376kb taking 4.90s
Record: #13,013 Memory: 1,355,200kb taking 5.14s
Record: #14,014 Memory: 1,355,184kb taking 5.43s
Record: #15,015 Memory: 1,355,344kb taking 5.72s
```

The file, unfortunately, is around ~20gb so I'll probably be dead by the time the whole thing is read at the rate of increase.  The code is (mainly) below but I suspect it's something to do with fgets() , but I am not sure what.

```
    $handle = fopen ($import_file, 'r');

    while ($line = fgets ($handle))
    {
        $data = json_decode ($line);

        save_record ($data, $line);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Commenting out 'save_record ($data, $line);' appears to do nothing.

Comment: Can you post the code for save_record? That is probably the key

Comment: Actually if I comment out the save_record () line it's still just as bad.

Comment: How are you getting that performance output? You have no performance logging in the code sample you provided. I suspect the problem is elsewhere. Do you have some more code that you're not showing us that might be relevant?

Comment: Yeah, we need to see more code. And you are 100% sure those seconds are not simply the overall time progressing? Just to exclude the possibility...

Comment: Yep, 99.9% sure, the total time adds up to 60s, which is the PHP timeout point.

Comment: @DCD can you show the full code?

Comment: Be sure to free up memory where you can, I had a similoa problem, and at big files, the script become slower, and after a while it failed with "memory full" error.

Comment: @DCD: where and how are you calculating the elapsed time? How are you calling your code?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is better to use system commands for reading these large files. I ran into something similar and here is a little trick I used:

```
$lines = exec("wc -l $filename");
for($i=1; $i <= $lines; $i++) {
   $line = exec('sed \''.$i.'!d\' '.$filename);

   // do what you want with the record here
}
```

I would not recommend this with files that cannot be trusted, but it runs fast since it pulls one record at a time using the system. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

According to Leigh Purdie comment, there are some performance issue on big files with `fgets`. If your JSON objects are bigger than his test lines, you might it the limits much faster

use http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php and specify a length limit

Answer (score 0):

Alright, a performance problem. Obviously something is going quadratic when it shouldn't, or more to the point, something that should be constant-time seems to be linear in the number of records dealt with so far. The first question is what's the minimal scrap of code that exhibits the problem. I would want to know if you get the same problematic behavior when you comment out all but reading the file line by line. If so, then you'll need a language without that problem. (There are plenty.) Anyway, once you see the expected time characteristic, add statements back in one-by-one until your timing goes haywire, and you'll have identified the problem.

You instrumented something or other to get the timings. Make sure those can't cause a problem by executing them alone 15000 times or so.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to find a way for me to more quickly go thru a 96G text file. The script I initially wrote took 15 hours to reach 0.1%...

I have tried some of the solutions suggested here, using stream_get_line, fgets and exec for sed. I ended up with a different approach that I thought I would share with anyone else stopping by this question.

Split the file up! :-)

On my freebsd box (also exists for linux and others) I have a command line utility named 'split'.

```
usage: split [-l line_count] [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
       split -b byte_count[K|k|M|m|G|g] [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
       split -n chunk_count [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
       split -p pattern [-a suffix_length] [file [prefix]]
```

So I ran :

```
split -l 25000 -a 3 /data/var/myfile.log /data/var/myfile-log/
```

Then I ended up with 5608 files in the /data/var/myfile-log/ directory, which could then all be processed one at time with a command like :

```
php -f do-some-work.php /data/var/myfile-log/*
```